# Texture is shown as being black

Tags: uv

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to apply textures to objects for using them in OpenGL. Everything worked perfectly until today, but now when I change the Viewport Shading to Texture in order to see how my texture is mapped on the object, the object turns black and I can't see anything.

Here is a screenshot to understand better what I'm talking about.

I tried adding a lamp because I thought that might light up the object, but it didn't work. What should I do? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-editor.

Comment: Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/uvs-not-updated-in-textured-view-when-in-glsl-material-mode. Did you turn on GLSL shading? In case it's used you might face with this problem if your scene is lit by Area lamp. Change it to any other and it will work as usual.

Comment: move your lamp above the object

Comment: The fastest way to get an accurate answer is if you share your file. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/